# How to find the distinct records when a value was changed in a table with daily snap shots

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that has a SNAP_EFF_DT (date the record was inserted into the table) field. All records are inserted on a daily basis to record any changes a specific record may have. I want to pull out only the dates and values when a change took place from a previous date.

I am using Teradata SQL Assistant to query this data. This is what I have so far:

```
SEL DISTINCT MIN(a.SNAP_EFF_DT) as SNAP_EFF_DT, CLIENT_ID, FAVORITE_COLOR
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
GROUP BY 2,3;
```

This does give me the first instance of a change to a specific color. However, if a customer first likes blue on 1/1/2019, then changes to green on 2/1/2019, and then changes back to blue on 3/1/2019 I won't get that last change in the results and will assume their current favorite color is green, when in fact it changed back to blue. I would like a code that returns all 3 changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `LAG` to compare the current and the previous row's color:

```
SELECT t.*,
   LAG(FAVORITE_COLOR)
   OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID
         ORDER BY SNAP_EFF_DT) AS prev_color
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE AS t
QUALIFY
   FAVORITE_COLOR <> prev_color
OR prev_color IS NULL
```

If your Teradata version doesn't support `LAG` switch to

```
   MIN(FAVORITE_COLOR)
   OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID
         ORDER BY SNAP_EFF_DT
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev_color
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `JOIN`

```
select ct.*
from CUSTOMER_TABLE ct left join
     CUSTOMER_TABLE ctprev
     on ctprev.client_id = ct.client_id AND
        ctprev.SNAP_EFF_DT = ct.SNAP_EFF_DT - interval '1' day
where ctprev.client_id is null or
      (ctprev.FAVORITE_COLOR <> ct.FAVORITE_COLOR or
       . . .
      );
```

Note:  This assumes that the values are not `null`, although the logic can be adjusted to handle `null` values as well.